# how to use dynemodb with lumen or laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, lumen

I want to use dynemodb and mysql both with lumen.

I have follow below steps,

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

from above url I have add package for aws sdk for lumen

and add my accesskey and secret key in .env file

in bootstrap/app.php

I have add `$app->register(Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class);`

Now I want to use dynemodb with lumen to execute query

for execute dynemodb query same as eloquent I have used below package.

https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb

now I have write my code in model as below,

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use BaoPham\DynamoDb\Facades\DynamoDb;
use BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbModel;

class CategoryMaster extends BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbModel
{
    protected $table = 'category_master'; 
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'category_name'];
    public static function listname()
    {
        $model = DynamoDbModel::where(['category_name' => 'blue']);
        $query = $model->get(); 
        echo"<pre>";print_r($query);die;
    }

}
```

it gives me arror like below,

```
FatalErrorException in CategoryMaster.php line 8:
Class 'App\Models\BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbModel' not found
```

can you help me to resolve thais issue to use dynemodb

Comment: what error do you get? Do not suppose that someone help without direct question.

Comment: I have added sdk for aws in lumen , done intial setup, now not able to find how can I set it's db details and all

Comment: how to use dynamodb table with lumen

Comment: https://github.com/digiaonline/lumen-dynamodb

Comment: above I have checked , it not worked for me

Comment: I have update my question, for my issue and flow,please check it

Comment: can you help me to find it out ,how to use dynemodb with lumen

Answer (score 1):

I implemented dynamodb in laravel project using baopham package.
In .env file define dynamodb credentials

```
DYNAMODB_CONNECTION=aws
DYNAMODB_KEY=***
DYNAMODB_SECRET=****
DYNAMODB_REGION=us-east-1
```

In Model file

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends \BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbModel
{
    protected $table = 'Users'; //table name
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

In controller file

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\User; //include your model file

 class UserController extends Controller
 {
    public function index()
    {
       $user = User::all(); // to get all data from user table
       return view('products.index')->with('user', $user);
     }
 }
```

for more referance refer https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb query section.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution,

I have followed below site step by step and I am able to connect to dynemo db with lumen and able to fire eloquent queries

```
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel
https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb
https://github.com/laravelista/lumen-vendor-publish
```